# Wide Space in citations

Tags: biblatex, spacing

I am writing for the first time an essay in Latex and struggling with the bilbiography. In the example given there is a wide space before different kind of citations. Is there a possibility to avoid this space? Thanks a lot!

```
\begin{filecontents}{MeineBib.bib} 
@book{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010,
    address = {Berlin},
    series = {Münchener {Texte} und {Untersuchungen} zur deutschen {Literatur} des {Mittelalters}},
    title = {Deutschsprachige {Beichten} im 13. und 14. {Jahrhundert}. {Editionen} und {Typologien} zur Überlieferungs-, {Text}- und {Gebrauchsgeschichte} vor dem {Hintergrund} der älteren {Tradition}},
    number = {138},
    publisher = {De Gruyter},
    author = {Bruchhold, Ullrich},
    year = {2010},
    keywords = {12e siècle-13e siècle, 13e siècle-14e siècle, Anthologie, Ausgabe, Beichte, Beichtspiegel, Bußbuch, Catholic Church, Confession, Confession (Prayer), Frühneuhochdeutsch, German, German literature, Germany, Geschichte 1200-1300, Geschichte 1200-1400, Geschichte 13. Jh, Geschichte 1300-1400, Geschichte 14. Jh, History, History and criticism, Hochschulschrift, Littérature allemande, Littérature chrétienne, Littérature religieuse, Middle High German, 1050-1500, Mittelhochdeutsch, Penance, [Sources], confession (sacrement), deutsche, littérature religieuse allemande},
}

\end{filecontents} 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %für Anführungszeichen


\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp,
sorting=nyvt, 
url=false,               % URL-Angaben ausgeschaltet 
doi=false,
isbn=false,
pagetracker=true,         % ebd. bei wiederholten Angaben (false=ausgeschaltet, page=Seite, spread=Doppelseite, true=automatisch) 
backend=biber
]{biblatex}



% Anpassungen der Form des LitVerz 
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{6pt} %Zeilenabstand zwischen den einzelnen LitVerz-Eintraegen

% Schrägstriche zwischen den Autoren 
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{/} 
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{/} 

  % Doppelpunkt nach Autor & Jahr im LitVerz 
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace} 
%Keine Anführungszeichen bei Zeitschriften
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
% Kapitälchen im Namen
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
% Sortierung der Autoren 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{page = { }, pages = { }}
% Titel von Artikeln und Beiträgen weder kursiv noch in Anfuehrungsstrichen 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}

\AtEveryBibitem{
    \clearlist{language}
}

\AtEveryCitekey{
    \clearlist{language}
}
%\citeauthor prints only the last name. This command prints first and last name.
\newrobustcmd*{\citefirstlastauthor}{\AtNextCite{\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}\citeauthor}

%Serie in Monographien ausschalten
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
       \step[fieldset=series, null]
    }
  }
}  
%Seriennummer in Monographien ausschalten
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
       \step[fieldset=number, null]
    }
  }
}  

\bibliography{MeineBib.bib} 

\title{Titel}
\author{Author}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}

 Text Text \cite{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010} Text Text Text \citeauthor{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010} \\
 
\footcite{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010}

\footnote{\fullcite{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010}}
 
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, thanks for including code on your first question! Could you please clarify which space you are referring to, I have ran your code, do you mean the space before and after in-text citations or the space before footnote citations (the indent)?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are referring to the extra space that is being included before the in-text citations, the code that is causing it is:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{
    \clearlist{language}
}
```

The reason it is including a space is due to there not being any `%`'s at the end of the brackets, not including `%`'s means Latex includes a space ([please see here for a better explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat#7459)).

So it should be:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \clearlist{language}%
}
```

Therefore, including the `%`'s in your code gives this:

[image]

Your code here properly commented:

```
\begin{filecontents}{MeineBib.bib} 
@book{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010,
    address = {Berlin},
    series = {Münchener {Texte} und {Untersuchungen} zur deutschen {Literatur} des {Mittelalters}},
    title = {Deutschsprachige {Beichten} im 13. und 14. {Jahrhundert}. {Editionen} und {Typologien} zur Überlieferungs-, {Text}- und {Gebrauchsgeschichte} vor dem {Hintergrund} der älteren {Tradition}},
    number = {138},
    publisher = {De Gruyter},
    author = {Bruchhold, Ullrich},
    year = {2010},
    keywords = {12e siècle-13e siècle, 13e siècle-14e siècle, Anthologie, Ausgabe, Beichte, Beichtspiegel, Bußbuch, Catholic Church, Confession, Confession (Prayer), Frühneuhochdeutsch, German, German literature, Germany, Geschichte 1200-1300, Geschichte 1200-1400, Geschichte 13. Jh, Geschichte 1300-1400, Geschichte 14. Jh, History, History and criticism, Hochschulschrift, Littérature allemande, Littérature chrétienne, Littérature religieuse, Middle High German, 1050-1500, Mittelhochdeutsch, Penance, [Sources], confession (sacrement), deutsche, littérature religieuse allemande},
}

\end{filecontents} 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %für Anführungszeichen


\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp,
sorting=nyvt, 
url=false,               % URL-Angaben ausgeschaltet 
doi=false,
isbn=false,
pagetracker=true,         % ebd. bei wiederholten Angaben (false=ausgeschaltet, page=Seite, spread=Doppelseite, true=automatisch) 
backend=biber
]{biblatex}



% Anpassungen der Form des LitVerz 
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{6pt} %Zeilenabstand zwischen den einzelnen LitVerz-Eintraegen

% Schrägstriche zwischen den Autoren 
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{/} 
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{/} 

  % Doppelpunkt nach Autor & Jahr im LitVerz 
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace} 
%Keine Anführungszeichen bei Zeitschriften
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
% Kapitälchen im Namen
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
% Sortierung der Autoren 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{page = { }, pages = { }}
% Titel von Artikeln und Beiträgen weder kursiv noch in Anfuehrungsstrichen 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearlist{language}%
}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \clearlist{language}%
}

%\citeauthor prints only the last name. This command prints first and last name.
\newrobustcmd*{\citefirstlastauthor}{\AtNextCite{\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}\citeauthor}

%Serie in Monographien ausschalten
\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map{%
      \pertype{book}%
       \step[fieldset=series, null]%
    }
  }
}  
%Seriennummer in Monographien ausschalten
\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map{%
      \pertype{book}%
       \step[fieldset=number, null]%
    }
  }
}  

\addbibresource{MeineBib.bib} 

\title{Titel}
\author{Author}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}

 Text Text \cite{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010} Text Text Text \citeauthor{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010} \\
 
\footcite{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010}

\footnote{\fullcite{bruchhold_deutschsprachige_2010}}
 
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: I forgot to add, use `\addbibresource{mein.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{mein.bib}.`